# Replace image sources in vbulletin

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, vbulletin

I want to add a script to the "headinclude" template of my vbulletin.
Because often I have to change the domain of the website, so some links, especially image links doesn't work after changing domain.
So I thought it would be better to add a jQuery script (or maybe javascript).
I have some links of images in one webpage as following:

```
  <div id=allimages>
    <span>
        <img src="http://olddomain.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=123&d=3321">
        <img src="http://olddomain.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=352&d=7541">
        <img src="http://olddomain.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=851&d=4853">
    </span>
  </div>
```

I want to change all olddomain.com to newdomain.org

How can I do it?